# If B’s chance to win one of these games is $\frac{9}{13}$, what is the value of $p$?

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are playing a game with dice where if one of them rolls higher than the other twice in a row, they will be declared winner. However, $B$ secretly has a weighted die that has a chance $p$ to land on $6$ and will land on anything else with the same probability. If $B$’s chance to win one of these games is $\frac{9}{13}$, what is the value of $p$?

Here's how I tried doing the problem.

Suppose the two dies weren't weighted. We can find the probability by just looking at the symmetry of the problem but in a more general case, we would use infinite series. The probability player $B$ gets twice in a row in first two turns is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ and if player $A$ gets higher on first turn and then player $B$ gets twice in a row, it's $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$. We can continue like this and add all of these cases to get an infinite series that sums to $\frac{1}{2}$.

We then need to find the probability that player $B$ has a greater roll than player $A$. Player $A$'s probability distribution can be thought of as $6$ concentric circles evenly spaced $1/6$ units apart. $B$'s probability distribution has $5$ concentric circles $\frac{1-p}{5}$ units apart and then a sixth circle $p$ units away. ($B$'s circles should all be under $A$'s corresponding circles or for the sixth circle, in the same position). For every ring, we can find the area in which player $B$'s circle is above player $A$'s. The sum of all of the areas is then the probability that player $B$ rolled a greater number than $A$. If the probability of that is $d$, then the probability of twice in a row is $\frac{d^2}{1-d}$ which equals $\frac{9}{13}$.

I got that the value of $p$ is $0.295$ though I could be wrong in calculating it but I think the general process is the right idea.

Comment: "However, $B$ secretly has a weighted die that has a chance $p$ to land on $6$ and will land on anything else with the same probability."  I am not understanding this.  A die has 6 sides.  Is the probability it will land on 6 "p" and the probability it will land on any other side also "p"?  I that case p= 1.  Or do you mean the probability it will land on "6" is p and the probability of any other one side is also p.  In that case, p= 1/6.

Comment: Why would $B$ have a $(1/2)^2$ chance to get two higher rolls than $A$ on the first turn? Wouldn't it be $25/144=(1/6(5/6+4/6+3/6+2/6+1/6))^2=0.17$? That is, what if they roll the same number?

Comment: Whoops! I forgot about that. So how would you approach the problem for a weighted die?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question badly. The probability it lands on 6 is p and the probability it lands on anything else is (1-p)/5.

Comment: I might be nitpicking here but what happens if the first two rolls are not conclusive (i.e. neither player beats the other in both rolls)?  Is the game declared a draw, or do they keep rolling until one player wins?  (The problem is easier if they do not keep playing, i.e. the game is simply drawn.)

Comment: They keep playing until one player gets two consecutive wins.

Comment: If you're sure they keep rolling...  First calculate $a, b, d$ which are respectively the prob that in a single roll A rolls higher, B rolls higher, or it's a Draw (they roll equal).  Note that $a+b+d = 1$.  Then to handle the "keep rolling" part, I would suggest using a small Markov Chain, or equivalently, a small set of recurrences calculating B winning from one of $3$ states: from no history (start of game, and every time after a tied roll), from A having won the previous roll, and, from B having won the previous roll.  Lots of tedious algebra ahead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start a fresh game: $B$ has $p$ chance to roll $6$ and $\frac{1-p}{5}$ chance to roll any other number while $A$ has $\frac{1}{6}$ for any number. Not considering these probabilities, what could happen in this game? There are three possibilities

$1)$ $B$ has just rolled a higher number so they only need one more to win

$2)$ A tie was just rolled in which case $B$ needs to win the next roll to get to $1)$. If $B$ loses, then they situation $3)$ happens

$3)$ $A$ has just rolled a higher number so $B$ needs to tie $A$ or roll higher than $A$ to get back to $1)$ or $2)$.

This can be represented by a graph

[image: Graph Representation]

Now, the game starts at the stalemate node. However, at any interior nodes (where the game is still being played), we move according to these rules

$1)$ Travel along the blue path if $B$ wins the roll

$2)$ Travel along the red path if $A$ wins the roll

$3)$ Travel along the black path if it is a stalemate

We can determine the probabilities for each path as follows

$$P(B\text{ wins when }B\text{ rolls a }6)=\frac{5}{6}$$

$$P(B\text{ wins when }B\text{ rolls a }5)=\frac{4}{6}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$P(B\text{ wins when }B\text{ rolls a }1)=\frac{0}{6}$$

Adding these together after multiplying by the probability that $B$ rolls that die we get

$$P(B\text{ wins roll})=p\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1-p}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{6}(4+3+2+1)=\frac{2p+3}{6}$$

The probability of a stalemate is

$$P(\text{Stalemate})=p\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1-p}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{6}(1+1+1+1+1)=\frac{1}{6}$$

which makes sense as this only depends on what $A$ rolls and is therefore independent of $B$. Then the probability that $A$ wins the roll is

$$P(A\text{ wins roll})=1-\frac{2p+3}{6}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1-p}{2}$$

Finally, If the game ends, then we are stuck in an infinite loop so the green edges have probability $1$. Having defined the probabilities of traveling along certain edges, we now turn to using [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) to figure out the probability of winning the game. If we label stalemate as node $1$, $B$ ahead as node $2$, $A$ ahead as node $3$, $B$ wins as node $4$, and $B$ loses as node $5$, then the transition matrix is

$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} (3 p+2) & \frac{1-p}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1-p}{2} & \frac{1}{6} (3 p+2) & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} (3 p+2) & 0 & 0 & \frac{1-p}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now, the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is

$$q(x)=\frac{1}{216} (1-x)^2 \left(-54 p^2 x-9 p^2+18 p x+3 p-216 x^3+36 x^2+66 x+6\right)$$

Does this have $0$ for a root for some $p\in [0,1]$? Setting $x=0$ gives us

$$0=q(0)=\frac{1}{216} \left(-9 p^2+3 p+6\right)$$

Solving for $p$ gives us $p=1,-\frac{2}{3}$. However, if $p=1$ then player $B$ has a $100\%$ chance of winning because $A$ can never win a roll so we can dismiss $p=1$. Also, since $p=-\frac{2}{3}<0$ we are assured that the matrix $P$ has non-zero eigenvalues for all possible values of $p\in [0,1)$. In fact, we can explicitly calculate the eigenvalues of $P$ using $q(x)$. Obviously, it has $1$ as a repeated eigenvalue. We must now solve

$$0=-54 p^2 x-9 p^2+18 p x+3 p-216 x^3+36 x^2+66 x+6$$

to get the other three. These are horrifying complicated but Mathematica is able to solve for them no problem. For now, let us just call them $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$. It is difficult to formally show but easy enough to see by plotting that for $p\in [0,1)$ the eigenvalues are unique and $|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|,|\lambda_3|\in (0,1)$ (remember this for later). Now, the eigenvector for the first eigenvalue of $1$ is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3 \left(3 p^3+2 p^2-13 p+8\right)}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 \frac{18 \left(p^2-2 p+1\right)}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 -\frac{-3 p^2+31 p-28}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

while the eigenvector for the second $1$ is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{(p-3) \left(9 p^2+12 p+4\right)}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 \frac{(p+9) (3 p+2)}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 \frac{2 \left(9 p^2+12 p+4\right)}{21 p^2-7 p+36} \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since these are clearly independent, $P$ is diagonalizable. That is, there exists invertible $S$ such that

$$S^{-1}P S=D$$

is diagonal. We know the columns of $S$ will just be the eigenvectors of $P$ while $D$ will be made of the eigenvalues of $P$. Thus,

$$P=SDS^{-1}=S\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)S^{-1}$$

Now, let $P_0$ be our starting condition. That is,

$$P_0=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In order to determine the probability of being on the $i$th node after $n$ steps, we simply have to perform $P_0 P^n$ and check the value in the $i$th column. For example, after $2$ steps we get

$$P_0 P^2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1-p}{12}+\frac{1}{36} (3 p+2)+\frac{1}{36} & \frac{1}{12} (1-p) (3 p+2)+\frac{1}{36} (3 p+2) & \frac{1}{12} (3 p+2) (1-p)+\frac{1-p}{12} &
   \frac{1}{36} (3 p+2)^2 & \frac{1}{4} (1-p)^2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This implies that $B$ has a $\frac{1}{36} (3 p+2)^2$ chance of being on node $4$ (and therefore winning) after two steps. Then

$$P_0 P^n=P_0 (SDS^{-1})^n=P_0 S D^n S^{-1}$$

Since $D$ is diagonal, we know

$$D^n=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda_1^n & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2^n & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_3^n \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since the probability the game finishes goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, we may as well take the limit of $D^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Since the eigenvalues all lie in the unit circle, their absolute value goes to $0$. Thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}D^n=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Calculating out the fourth entry in $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_0 S D^n S^{-1}$ gives us

$$P(B\text{ wins})=-\frac{(p-3) \left(9 p^2+12 p+4\right)}{21 p^2-7 p+36}$$

Solving this for $\frac{9}{13}$ gives us

$$-117 p^3+6 p^2+479 p-168=0$$

which has roots at

$$p_1=\frac{2}{117}-\frac{3737\ 5^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{234 \sqrt[3]{-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}}}-\frac{1}{234} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{5 \left(-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}\right)}=-2.15624$$

$$p_2=\frac{2}{117}-\frac{3737\ 5^{2/3} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{234 \sqrt[3]{-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}}}-\frac{1}{234} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{5 \left(-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}\right)}=0.360551$$

$$p_3=\frac{1}{117} \left(2+\frac{3737\ 5^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}}}+\sqrt[3]{5 \left(-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}\right)}\right)= 1.84697$$

Since $p_2$ is the only one that fits our conditions, we conclude

$$p=\frac{2}{117}-\frac{3737\ 5^{2/3} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{234 \sqrt[3]{-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}}}-\frac{1}{234} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{5 \left(-218765+702 i \sqrt{432385}\right)}=0.360551 $$